# How do I emit only last matching element in sequence?

Tags: system.reactive, reactive-programming

I have a stream of events that are in a sorted order. Each event is part of a group that has a key property - its ID. The events have differing values for non-ID properties. I wish to ignore all but the final event before the ID changes. For example

```
{ID:1, Prop: "V1"}, {ID:1,  Prop:"V2"}, {ID:1,  Prop:"V3"}, {ID:2,  Prop:"V1"}, {ID:2,  Prop:"V2"}, {ID:2,  Prop:"V3"}, {ID:2,  Prop:"V25"}, {ID:3,  Prop:"V1"}, {ID:3,  Prop:"V8"}
```

I would want to emit only:

```
 {ID:1,  Prop:"V3"},{ID:2,  Prop:"V25"},{ID:3,  Prop:"V8"}
```

I had used `GroupBy` id and then `TakeLast(1)` however `TakeLast`, as far as I understand, will wait until stream completes and would seem likely to take a lot more memory for longer. I know that I have seen the last of that sequence of IDs as soon as I see different ID in the stream - so I want to emit the value as soon as I see a change in the key property. I guess kind of like `distinctUntilChange` but giving me the last value.

I would expect to emit the first element as soon as I see the first element with `ID:2` in the stream.

I thought about buffering or something but still getting my head around reactive. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
source.Buffer(2, 1)
      .Where(i => i.Count == 2 ? (i[0].ID != i[1].ID) : true)
      .Select(i => i[0])
```

Keep a running buffer of 2 latest elements of the `Observable`. 
If the ID changes or the buffer contains only one element (last element), emit the first item of the buffer.

Comment: I thought it involved buffering. Maybe I will yet achieve mastery over streams!